# Отображение сайта в браузерах.

Tags: браузер

Сайт не отображается в гугл хроме полностью, видно только верхнее меню и логотип. В чем может быть проблема?

Кодировка - utf8.

Comment: Ссылочку можно? А то экстрасенсов тут врядли много.

Comment: Да?))) а я думала что всё же они есть, как их там... экстрасенсы))) http://distira.ru

Добавлю ещё, что в некоторых версиях хрома, если часто обновлять страницу, информация иногда появляется.

Comment: В каких браузерах он отображается полностью? Что именно не отображается? При чем тут кодировка? У Вас проблема с символами? Применяли ли вы вообще css?

Comment: Дык, многие на кодировку мне указывали на др. форумах. Вот я сразу и сказала что не в этом проблема) 
Отображается полностью в firefox, в некоторых версиях Chromium, и opera. Не отображается информация, логотип и верхнее меню отображается везде.
LordyGL, я только учусь поэтому спрашиваю, нет всего я не знаю конечно. Я не прошу решить проблему, просто хочу понять в каком направлении двигаться мне.

Comment: Да не, это просто ряд вопросов. Я прост думал что сайт на тестовом сервере. Через тестовый сервер - все ок. Одинаково в ie, chrom, firefox

Comment: Одинаково отображается всё или одинаково видно только меню и логотип?)

Comment: Отображается абсолютно все. Понять в чем проблема сложновато изза этого

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для `#wrapper` поставьте `width:100%`.

Answer (score 1):

Если никто не поможет, то советую обратиться сюда: [Что делать, если мой сайт отображается неправильно в Google Chrome?](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=ru&answer=106726)